# Xcode: "loginUser" couldn't be opened when trying to read a JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am building an app that logins the users by reading a JSON, but something weird is happening and I do not understand why. So, when a user enters a valid username & password, it works fine but when a user enters them wrongfully, I am getting this error:

```
“loginUser” couldn’t be opened.
```

This is the code I am using for this:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://www.url.com/url/loginUser?loginAlias=" +
txtUser.text! + "&loginPassword=" + txtPassword.text!) {
```

Extended code: https://textuploader.com/dnq7r (I was having troubles pasting it here)

I have tried to see the JSON through a web browser and it has this structure when a user enters a valid username & password:

```
{"alias":"user","firstLogin":true,"id":146,"isEnllum":false,"latitude":00.0000,
"longitude":0.000000,"townId":2,"townStr":"Town1","reply":1,"replyStr":"","role"
:2,"token":"yyjn7q0cia","urlVersion":"https:\/\/we.tl\/t-CX3jqO9Si8"}
```

But when not:

```
{"error":3,"isEnllum":false,"townId":2,"reply":2,"replyStr":"Username &
password are wrong","urlVersion":"https:\/\/we.tl\/t-CX3jqO9Si8"}
```

As you can see, both JSON files have the same structure, so I that is why I can't figure out what is wrong.

For the moment I can manage when a user enters a username & password wrongfully by using try and catch:

```
catch {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message: 
      "Username & password are wrong", preferredStyle: 
      UIAlertController.Style.alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: 
      UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:nil))
      self.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)
      print("Error: ",error.localizedDescription) /*this prints “loginUser” couldn’t be 
                                                  opened.*/
}
```

Although, I would like to know the reason of why is this happening, and fix it if it is possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the “loginUser”? Can you extended the code?

Comment: Alright, I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using the method `Data(contentOf:)` method to synchronously fetch data from a network URL. In the second case (empty/wrong username/password), the URL string formed doesn't correspond to an existing network resource, hence the error.
The error effectively tells you resource not found, so you can use the error thrown to show custom messages to the user (instead of `if(user=="" || password=="")`).

You can print the URL you're hitting and check if it's valid in the browser directly.

On a different note, making network requests synchronously [isn't recommended](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407864-init) as it can block your threads, UI and make your app crash, instead use URLSession's async tasks to achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have had to watch a video in order to help me because I did not know how to make network request async. On the other hand, I have figured out what was going on, it was not due to the if sentence, the problem was the Decodable structure, since the token field does not exist in the other JSON file, so I have fixed it by dividing both Decodable structs. So, now I have one for the reply field, and another one for the token field.